# How can I remove all array data when using nested SnapshotListeners?

Tags: ios, arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So whenever I add new data, both of my snapshot listeners are executed and the new data gets appended to 'dataArray' which is located outside of my LoadData Function. So what I figured I had to do is reset the data whenever new data get's added so not to duplicate my tableview data. So what I did is I added `self.dataArray.removeAll()` inside of my top listener, but how would I go about reseting the data for when the other listener gets executed as well?

```
struct Days: Decodable {
    var dow : String
    var workouts : [Workouts]
}

struct Workouts: Decodable {
    var workout : String    
}

        var dayCount = 0
        var dataArray = [Days]()


        //MARK: - viewDidLoad()
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            vcBackgroundImg()
            navConAcc()

            picker.delegate = self
            picker.dataSource = self

            tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellID)
            tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

            Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
                self.userIdRef = user!.uid
                self.rootCollection = Firestore.firestore().collection("/users/\(self.userIdRef)/Days")

                self.loadData { (Bool) in
                    if Bool == true {
                        self.dayCount = self.dataArray.count
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }

            }

        }

        //MARK: - Load Data
        func loadData(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()){

            let group = DispatchGroup()

            self.rootCollection.addSnapshotListener ({ (snapshot, err) in

                if let err = err
                {
                    print("Error getting documents: \(err.localizedDescription)");
                }
                else {

                    guard let dayDocument = snapshot?.documents else { return }

                    self.dataArray.removeAll()

                    for day in dayDocument {

                        group.enter()

                        self.rootCollection.document(day.documentID).collection("Workouts").addSnapshotListener {(snapshot, err) in

                            var workouts = [Workouts]()

                            let workoutDocument = snapshot!.documents

                            try! workoutDocument.forEach({doc in

                                let tester: Workouts = try doc.decoded()
                                let workoutString = tester.workout
                                let newWorkout = Workouts(workout: workoutString)
                                workouts.append(newWorkout)
                            })

                            let dayTitle = day.data()["dow"] as! String

                            let newDay = Days(dow: dayTitle, workouts: workouts)

                            self.dataArray.append(newDay)

                            group.leave()
                        }

                    }

                }
                group.notify(queue: .main){
                    completion(true)
                }
            })
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried to declare your `var workout` outside the `for` and then, using the `removeAll()` after the end of the `self.rootCollection`? I believe this way, you would have your array created and it would clean the data after every read from the database.

Comment: Ok I figured it out. Basically I cannot have nested listeners because whenever only the inside listener executes in order to execute the outside for loop properly, I actually need both listeners to execute, so I just changed the inside listener to a `get` and I called the loadData function manually whenever I'm adding a workout object under an already existing Day Section.

Comment: Hi @Rapsln4 glad to hear that you find the problem! Please, consider posting the solution as answer, so other member can check it, as well.